# Jquery UI Tabs классы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui, tabs

В общем  такая проблема, в стандартной структуре этого плагина навигационные табы  находятся сверху, мне же  нужно, чтобы они были снизу, но  при  попытке поменять местами в HTML они просто отказываются работать.  Пробовал переназначать классы с помощью json'a classes{}, но  ничего не выходит. Подскажите, можно ли переназначить классы, чтобы  табы были снизу, а контент над ними?

```
 <div id="tabs-2">
       <ul class="tabs-container">
         <li class="grid tab-content" id="tabs-21></li>
         <li class="grid tab-content" id="tabs-22></li>
         <li class="grid tab-content" id="tabs-23></li>
       </ul>
      <ul class="articlesNav">
        <li class="btn prev invisLink change"><span><</span></li>
        <li class="tabItem"><a href="#tabs-21">1</a></li>
        <li class="tabItem"><a href="#tabs-22">2</a></li>
        <li class="tabItem"><a href="#tabs-23">3</a></li>
        <li class="btn next invisLink change"><span>></span></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Пробовал это

```
  $( "#tabs-2" ).tabs({
        classes: {
            "ui-tabs-nav": "articlesNav",
            "ui-tabs-panel": "tabs-container"
        }
    });
```

Comment: берете в примере https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ `ul` ставите после дивов с контентом, и табы внизу сами по себе. Остается только стили перекрыть, чтобы границы и отступы поменять местами (либо перевернуть кнопки вниз головой)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос закрыт.  Сделал контент не списком, а дивами как в  примере и заработало.

Comment: Может подскажите как сделать стрелки переключения между табами?